# Fuga das Galinhas - Problema de Backtracking

Tags: java

Estou implementando um problema em Java. O problema consiste em um tabuleiro NxN, em onde é colocado uma galinha e X lobos. Eu recebo o tamanho do tabuleiro,  a posição da galinha, o número de lobos e a posição dos lobos via entrada padrão, mais ou menos assim:

```
8     //tamanho do tabuleiro
2 3   //coluna e linha da galinha
3     //quantidade de lobos
6 0   //coluna e linha lobo1
3 7   //coluna e linha lobo2
2 1   //coluna e linha lobo3
```

O problema tem as seguintes regras:

> - A galinha pode se mover uma única casa nas posições norte, sul, este, oeste
> - Os lobos podem se mover uma casa em qualquer direção
> - Em uma jogada, a galinha se move em uma das 4 direções possíveis
> - Os lobos se moverão depois da galinha
> - Se um lobo estiver na mesma linha/coluna da galinha, ele se move apenas na linha/coluna, perseguindo a galinha
> - Se ele não estiver na mesma linha/coluna da galinha, ele se move na diagonal correta para a perseguição
> - Depois de todos os movimentos, é verificado se a galinha foi capturada

O problema consiste em desenvolver um algoritmo baseado em *backtracking* que, após 10 rodadas, descobre se a galinha consegue fugir ou não dos lobos.

Meu problema está no *backtracking* dos lobos. Após a galinha ser capturada em uma primeira vez, eu consigo fazer ela voltar para a posição anterior para tentar outra alternativa, mas não consigo fazer os lobos voltarem para a posição anterior. Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
public class Galinha {
    protected int X;
    protected int Y;

    public Galinha(int x, int y){
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    protected Galinha thisClone() {
        Galinha g = new Galinha(this.X, this.Y);
        return g;
    }
}



public class Lobo {
    protected int X;
    protected int Y;

    public Lobo(int x, int y){
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public void persegueGalinha(Galinha g){
        if( this.X > g.X)
            this.X--;
        if( this.X < g.X)
            this.X++;
        if(this.Y > g.Y)
            this.Y--;
        if(this.Y < g.Y)
            this.Y++;
    }

    public boolean comeuGalinha(Galinha g){
        return (X == g.X && Y == g.Y);
    }

    public Lobo thisClone() {
        Lobo l = new Lobo(this.X, this.Y);
        return l;
    }
}



public class TrabComplex {

    private static char[][] tabuleiro;
    private static Galinha galinha;
    private static Lobo[] lobos;
    private static int nroLobos;
    private static int rodada = 100;
    private static int cont = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int tamanho = 8;
        tabuleiro = new char[tamanho][tamanho];
        galinha = new Galinha(3, 1);
        tabuleiro[galinha.X][galinha.Y] = 'G';
        nroLobos = 3;
        lobos = new Lobo[nroLobos];

        Lobo l1 = new Lobo(7, 0);
        Lobo l2 = new Lobo(0, 6);
        Lobo l3 = new Lobo(3, 6);

        lobos[0] = l1;
        lobos[1] = l2;
        lobos[2] = l3;

        tabuleiro[l1.X][l1.Y] = 'L';
        tabuleiro[l2.X][l2.Y] = 'L';
        tabuleiro[l3.X][l3.Y] = 'L';
        moveGalinha(galinha, lobos);
    }

    public static void printMatriz() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tabuleiro.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabuleiro.length; j++) {
                if (tabuleiro[i][j] == 'L') {
                    System.out.print("L");
                } else if (tabuleiro[i][j] == 'G') {
                    System.out.print("G");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(".");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void moveGalinha(Galinha galinhaLoop, Lobo[] lobosLoop) {
        Galinha galinhaAux = galinhaLoop.thisClone();
        cont++;
        printMatriz();
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        Lobo[] lobosAux = cloneLobos(lobosLoop);
        for (int x = galinhaLoop.X - 1; x <= galinhaLoop.X + 1; x++) {

            if (cont < rodada && x > -1 && x < 8) {

                tabuleiro[galinhaLoop.X][galinhaLoop.Y] = '.';

                galinhaAux.X = x;
                galinhaAux.Y = galinhaLoop.Y;
                tabuleiro[x][galinhaAux.Y] = 'G';

                for (int i = 0; i < lobos.length; i++) {

                    tabuleiro[lobosLoop[i].X][lobosLoop[i].Y] = '.';
                    Lobo loboAux = lobosLoop[i].thisClone();
                    loboAux.X = lobosLoop[i].X;
                    loboAux.Y = lobosLoop[i].Y;
                    loboAux.persegueGalinha(galinhaLoop);
                    if (!TestaPosicaoLobo(loboAux.X, loboAux.Y)) {
                        loboAux.X = lobosLoop[i].X;
                        loboAux.Y = lobosLoop[i].Y;
                        tabuleiro[lobosLoop[i].X][lobosLoop[i].Y] = 'L';
                    }
                    tabuleiro[loboAux.X][loboAux.Y] = 'L';
                    lobosAux[i] = loboAux;

                    if (lobosLoop[i].comeuGalinha(galinhaLoop)) {
                        System.out.println("Lobo pegou a galinha!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                moveGalinha(galinhaAux, lobosAux);
            }
        }
        for (int y = galinhaLoop.Y - 1; y <= galinhaLoop.Y + 1; y++) {

            if (cont < rodada && y > -1 && y < 8) {

                tabuleiro[galinhaLoop.X][galinhaLoop.Y] = '.';

                galinhaAux.X = galinhaLoop.X;
                galinhaAux.Y = y;
                tabuleiro[galinhaAux.X][y] = 'G';

                for (int i = 0; i < lobos.length; i++) {

                    tabuleiro[lobosLoop[i].X][lobosLoop[i].Y] = '.';
                    Lobo loboAux = lobosLoop[i].thisClone();
                    loboAux.X = lobosLoop[i].X;
                    loboAux.Y = lobosLoop[i].Y;
                    loboAux.persegueGalinha(galinhaLoop);
                    if (!TestaPosicaoLobo(loboAux.X, loboAux.Y)) {
                        loboAux.X = lobosLoop[i].X;
                        loboAux.Y = lobosLoop[i].Y;
                        tabuleiro[lobosLoop[i].X][lobosLoop[i].Y] = 'L';
                    }
                    tabuleiro[loboAux.X][loboAux.Y] = 'L';
                    lobosAux[i] = loboAux;

                    if (lobosLoop[i].comeuGalinha(galinhaLoop)) {
                        System.out.println("Lobo pegou a galinha!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                moveGalinha(galinhaAux, lobosAux);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean TestaPosicaoLobo(int x, int y) {
        return tabuleiro[x][y] != 'L';
    }

    private static Lobo[] cloneLobos(Lobo[] listaLobos) {
        Lobo[] lobos = new Lobo[nroLobos];
        for (int i = 0; i < listaLobos.length; i++) {
            lobos[i] = listaLobos[i].thisClone();
        }
        return lobos;
    }

   private boolean LobosComeramGalinha(Lobo[] listaLobos, Galinha g){
       for(int i = 0; i < listaLobos.length; i++){
           if(listaLobos[i].X == g.X && listaLobos[i].Y == g.Y){
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: Desculpa, mas o que é backtracing? Poderia esclarecer melhor qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Backtracking é um metodo de construção de algoritmos.Ele funciona basicamente assim:Uma busca inicial em um programa com backtracking segue o padrão busca em profundidade, ou seja, a árvore é percorrida sistematicamente de cima para baixo e da esquerda para direita. Quando essa pesquisa falha, ou é encontrado um nodo terminal da árvore, entra em funcionamento o mecanismo de backtracking.Esse procedimento faz com que o sistema retorne pelo mesmo caminho percorrido com a finalidade de encontrar soluções alternativas.Ou seja, nada mais é do que um mecanismo de "voltar atras".Se algo falha, volta.

Comment: Tens de manter um registo dos nodos que já percorreste para fazer isso.

Comment: Usa o padrão de projeto [Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo que você não tente manter um histórico das posições de cada animal manualmente. Ao invés disso use recursividade e deixe a própria pilha de execução manter esse histórico.

É o que faz por exemplo o algoritmo de [*flood-fill* recursivo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Stack-based_recursive_implementation_.28Four-way.29), no qual você pode se basear para implementar sua solução.

O *flood-fill* é um algoritmo de processamento de imagens que [altera, pixel por pixel, a cor de uma região de uma imagem por outra cor](http://inventwithpython.com/blogstatic/floodfill/floodfill4.png?1b9ca7). A implementação recursiva do algoritmo parte de um pixel inicial dentro dessa região e vai preenchendo os pixels adjacentes (acima, à direita, abaixo e à esquerda) de maneira recursiva. Se o pixel estiver em um local em que não deveria estar (por exemplo fora da área da imagem, ou sobre uma cor já preenchida ou diferente da cor inicial) ele faz *backtracking*, ou seja, retorna imediatamente e a recursividade entra em ação para atuar sobre o próximo pixel, fazendo isso até que a região esteja totalmente preenchida.

Estude esse algoritmo e veja como ele pode ser usado para resolver o seu problema. Basicamente você terá um método que recebe uma cópia das coordenadas x, y da galinha e dos lobos e testa se a galinha foi pega ou se ela não pode estar na posição atual (por ser fora do tabuleiro ou a posição de um lobo), retornando imediatamente do método nesses dois casos. Lembrando que, ao contrário do *flood-fill* em que a movimentação é de um único elemento (o pixel), no caso da fuga das galinhas a movimentação é representada pela movimentação de todos os animais no tabuleiro, ou seja, um passo da galinha e em seguida um passo de cada lobo.

Acho que essa informação já é suficiente para queimar um pouco dos neurônios e resolver. Mais que isso e eu acabo dando a solução pronta. :)